# How to set delegate of viewControllers in TabbarController?

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates

**EDit:**

I have tabbarcontroller with two tabs, first tab I have a viewController , second tab I have navigationViewController with **two stack of ViewControllers with tableView.**

Tab1--->VC1

Tab2--->NVC-->fistVC1----push to----->secondVC2.

my code to push:

fistVC1.m

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
       if (indexPath.section == 0 & (indexPath.row == 0)) {

    _secondVC2 = [[secondVC2 alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_secondVC2 animated:YES];
    [_secondVC2 release];
```

what I need to do is set VC1 as a delegate of secondVC2, when secondVC2 cell selected i Want to send message to the VC1.

how can i do this ,please give me some advise.

i tried like blow:

secondVC2.h

```
 @protocol secondVC2Delegate <NSObject>

   - (void)someMethod;

 @end
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @interface secondVC2 :UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
 {
     id<secondVC2Delegate>delegate;
 }

@property (nonatomic ,assign) id<secondVC2Delegate>delegate;

 @end;
```

secondVC2.m

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     NSLog(@"delegate%@",self.delegate);
     if (indexPath.row == 0) {
      [self.delegate someMethod];
     }
```

VC1.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import"secondVC2"
    @interface VC1 :UIViewController<secondVC2Delegate>{

     secondVC2 *tvc2;

    }
    @property (nonatomic ,retain) secondVC2 *tvc2;

    - (void)someMethod;

    @end;
```

VC1.m

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
       tvc2 = [secondVC2 alloc] init];
       tvc2.delegate = self;
    }
```

but the delegate kept released and i got nil delegate in the secondVC2 which i dont know why .
   So how could i achive this ?

Comment: `@protocol TableVC2 <NSObject>`? are you sure about this?

Comment: Edited it . mistyped.

Comment: Are you sure that tvc2 in VC1.viewDidLoad is the same instance with the one in Tab2--->NVC-->TableVC1---->tableVC2 ?

Comment: How are you going from TableVC1 to TableVC2? Segue or pushing in code?

Comment: rdelmar , thanks for the reply. I am pushing it in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ViewController1 *viewController1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
ViewController2 *viewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
viewController1.delegate = viewController2;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:@[viewController1, navigationController]];
```

You could also look into `NSNotificationCenter`.